# In docker, what are these POSTROUTING iptables rules for?

Tags: linux, iptables, docker

Docker creates a MASQUERADE iptables rule for every container that has an exposed port (in this example I have 5 containers with exposed port 3500):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L -v -n

<snip>

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 42 packets, 2650 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    <snip>
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:3500
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:3500
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.4           172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:3500
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.5           172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:3500
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.7           172.17.0.7           tcp dpt:3500

<snip>
```

If I understand things correctly, this means that when we have a packet with source and destination equal and destined for the docker container, the MASQUERADE target should apply. But when would this happen?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/

Comment: @alexus this only mentions masquerading for the bridge network, not the individual containers

Answer (score 0):

Although this thread is older, this question has now been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802089/cant-understand-docker-iptables-rule

In short - This is supposed for an edge case, in most cases, what interests you is this rule:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s <Docker subnet> ! -o <Docker interface> -j MASQUERADE
```

e.g.:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/24 ! -o br-a9173b54dfbd -j MASQUERADE
```